# MPMoviePlayerController iOS stream m3u8 file not working

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, m3u8, mpmoviewcontroller

im trying to play a m3u8 live streaming file by using this code:

```
       NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.streaming507.com:1935/TVBlast/TVBlast/playlist.m3u8"];



    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

        [self.view addSubview:mp.view];

        [mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    mp.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

        [mp play];


}
```

when i copy/paste streaming507.com:1935/TVBlast/TVBlast/playlist.m3u8 in my device in safari browser it plays perfect and it works good how i can fix this?

I dont know what im doing wrong

thank you

Comment: You need to mention the movie source type as streaming before playing the video.Try this mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

Comment: I am not sure but try replacing [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault]; with mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

Comment: i just modified the code in my main thread, but same it doesnt play the m3u8 file

Comment: when i copy/paste http://www.streaming507.com:1935/TVBlast/TVBlast/playlist.m3u8 in my device in safari browser it plays perfect

Comment: Are you able to play any other video from your player?

Comment: i just fix it by using this: <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/> i was getting in console of xcode App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

i fix the problem by copy/paste this in my info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Do you see where is says DANGER? Well, it says that for a reason

Comment: what you recommend? to just allow the m3u8 file how?

Comment: I would say add the specific domain name to app transport security, because allows arbitrary loads is a security issue... but for some reason I think you might have to allow arbitrary loads when playing a m3u8 file